# Android InAppBilling PurchaseStatusAPI

Tags: android, authentication, oauth-2.0, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I want to establish a content provider server whose different contents have to be bought using the Android InAppBilling API. If a mobile user buys an item he gets a unique purchase token. If the user wants to download some content from my server I can use that token to check if the purchase is valid and thus the user is allowed to download the content.

But how do I check if that purchase token really belongs to the user my server is talking to? Is there an existing authentication mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

as you can see at the end of image there are "response code" you can use it like developer docs

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
   if (requestCode == 1001) {           
      int responseCode = data.getIntExtra("RESPONSE_CODE", 0);
      String purchaseData = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA");
      String dataSignature = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE");
        
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
         try {
            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(purchaseData);
            String sku = jo.getString("productId");
            alert("You have bought the " + sku + ". Excellent choice, 
               adventurer!");
          }
          catch (JSONException e) {
             alert("Failed to parse purchase data.");
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
   }
}
```

if not enough also you can check [In-app Billing Reference (IAB Version 3)](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html)

well I am trying to help not a prof..

Comment: but how can I avoid that this response data is extracted by network monitoring or apk reverse engineering and is used by someone else to download the content from my server. The response data should be valid for only one user, right? Then that user has to prove that it's really his, when communicating with my server?